# Display the total for a single columns values in Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to display a box at the bottom of my ActiveAdmin index page where it will total all of the values of the collection and display this total value. I am trying to sum the value of the column :number_books and I am currently using this code as suggested when someone answered a similar question a few years ago.

This does not appear to be having any impact on my index page as nothing is visibly changing on the index page for :orders.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
index do       
      column :email  
      column :customer_name     
      column :number_books
      column :street_address
      column :state
      column :zip_code
      column :total

      default_actions

      div class: "panel" do
        h3 "Total amount: #{collection.pluck(:number_books).reduce(:+)}"
      end
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had to define this new index page I was creating as the default, otherwise activeadmin uses the default index page and ignores my custom one. I also had to change default_actions to simply actions and this now works great!

the working code is:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
index default: true do       
      column :email  
      column :customer_name     
      column :number_books
      column :street_address
      column :state
      column :zip_code
      column :total

      actions

      div class: "panel" do
        h3 "Total amount: #{collection.pluck(:number_books).reduce(:+)}"
      end
    end 
end
```